# Add image below existing image in UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, subview

I'm subclassing UIImageView to create sprites, which move around the screen in an app I'm working on. I have a new requirement to add another image to the view, underneath the original view. If I were building this from scratch, I'd composite them as subviews of a common view and use the `sendSubviewToBack` method for the subview containing the image that needs to go to the back. I'll re-engineer things this way if I have to, but if there's a way to do this in the existing UIImageView, I'd rather do that.

Think of the new image as a shadow or light beam from the original image. They move together, but the original image needs to be on top.

The view will always contain the original image, but it may or may not contain the new image.

Comment: I want to avoid drawRect, if possible. But if I did use it, I'm not sure I follow how I'd do what you suggest.